# Problem using Intel integrated graphics GPU (Xorg)

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, gpu, intel-graphics, mesa

I am trying to get the Intel integrated GPU working with my Parabola (Arch variant) desktop PC. According to `lspci`, the GPU is:

```
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

I have reconfigured my xorg.conf files to point to it; however, when I run `startx`, I get the following error in the Xorg log file:

```
[  1611.090] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[  1611.101] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[  1611.101] (EE) AIGLX error: unable to load driver i965
```

So, it seems to not be able to find the i965 driver for the GPU. Looking in `/usr/lib/dri` verifies that the driver file is not there:

```
# ls /usr/lib/dri
crocus_dri.so  iris_dri.so    nouveau_dri.so  r600_dri.so      swrast_dri.so      vmwgfx_dri.so
d3d12_dri.so   kms_swrast_dri.so  r300_dri.so     radeonsi_dri.so  virtio_gpu_dri.so  zink_dri.so
```

*However*, if I check the file list for the mesa package I have installed, it says the file should be installed:

```
# pacman -Fl mesa | grep dri
mesa usr/include/GL/internal/dri_interface.h
mesa usr/lib/dri/
mesa usr/lib/dri/i915_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/nouveau_vieux_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/r200_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/r300_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/radeon_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/virtio_gpu_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so
mesa usr/lib/pkgconfig/dri.pc
mesa usr/share/drirc.d/
mesa usr/share/drirc.d/00-mesa-defaults.conf
```

**However**, if I check the mesa package tar archive, that driver file is clearly not present:

```
# tar -tf mesa-22.2.1-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst | grep dri
usr/include/GL/internal/dri_interface.h
usr/lib/dri/
usr/lib/dri/crocus_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/d3d12_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/iris_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/nouveau_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/r300_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/r600_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/virtio_gpu_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/vmwgfx_dri.so
usr/lib/dri/zink_dri.so
usr/lib/pkgconfig/dri.pc
usr/share/drirc.d/
usr/share/drirc.d/00-mesa-defaults.conf
```

So, what's going on here then? Is 'i965_dri.so' supposed to be provided with mesa, or am I supposed to get it from somewhere else? If it is supposed to be there, I should probably file an issue report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo pacman -Fy` to refresh your package file databases. `i965_dri.so` is in the `mesa-amber` package:

```
↪  pacman -F i965_dri.so
multilib/lib32-mesa-amber 21.3.9-2
    usr/lib32/dri/i965_dri.so
extra/mesa-amber 21.3.9-2
    usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! However, it seems I can't have both mesa and mesa-amber installed at the same time? I have an NVidia GPU, but had hoped to set up the Intel one as a backup, as I have had problems with the NVidia drivers lately.